# Can't access dictionary with dot notation in Robotframework

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, robotframework

I have embedded dictionaries like this:

```
${json}=    Create Dictionary ......(value pairs)
${request}= Create Dictionary   body=${json}
${return}=  Create Dictionary   request=${request}
```

I can access original key-value pairs like for example this:

```
${return.request.body.type}
```

It all works fine. However, I get this error:

```
Resolving variable '${detail_call.response.json.type}' failed: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'type'
```

When I try to create the initial json object vice-versa - by decoding it from string like this:

```
${decoded_json}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    json.JSONDecoder.Decode ${response.content}
${response.json}=   Set Variable If '${decode_status}' == 'PASS'    ${decoded_json} ${null}
${detail_call}=    Create Dictionary    response=${response}
```

and accessing it via dot notation:

```
${detail_call.response.json.type}
```

When I log the string, I can clearly see there is key "type" with a value assigned. It even works when I access it with brackets:

```
${detail_call.response.json['type']}
```

Do you have any idea, why I can't use dot notation if the dictionary was created with JSONDecoder?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. You don't access dictionaries (that is, `dict`s specifically) using dot notation in Python in the first place, unless you're using a different dictionary implementation that allows that. Dot notation is used for attributes of objects, but `JSONDecoder` returns `dict`s, so it's perfectly normal to use brackets to access their keys. Also your sample code doesn't seem to be valid Python, is that syntax specific to the Robot framework?

Comment: I think you've nailed it, I guess it is indeed different dict implementation. I'm not very familiar with python, only with robot and in it's syntax it is possible to access dicts with dots.

Comment: It's entirely possible Robot just creates plain objects, not dictionaries, since it's not really much harder to set attributes in Python dynamically.

Comment: It is, thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As millimoose suggested, JSONDecoder returns python dictionary which is different from robotframework's own dictionary. I haven't found official way to convert python dict to robot dict so I have implemented my own:

```
Convert Python Dictionary
[Arguments]    ${python_dict}
[Documentation]    Converts Python dictionary to Robot dictionary.
@{keys}=    Get Dictionary Keys    ${python_dict}
${robot_dict}=    Create Dictionary
:FOR    ${key}    IN    @{keys}
\    Set To Dictionary    ${robot_dict}    ${key}=${python_dict['${key}']}
[Return]    ${robot_dict}
```

In case you need to convert robot dict to python dict, you can use [Convert To Dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Convert%20To%20Dictionary) keyword from Collections library.

Answer (score 0):

Robot Framework has its own dictionary class [DotDict](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/autodoc/robot.utils.html#robot.utils.dotdict.DotDict), which allows accessing (nested) dictionaries using dot notation. Using the Robot Framework DSL there are three ways to create a DotDict:

1. With the keyword [Create Dictionary](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20Dictionary) (as you already found out)
2. [Creating a dictionary variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-dictionary-variables) in the Settings section
3. [Assigning a dictionary variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#return-values-from-keywords) (e.g. `&{robot_dict}`) as the return value of a keyword

Option 3. is what you were looking for.